# how to print variable/array out of function

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I need the array($project_Ids) out of function any suggestion.
This is in view

 I can't call the function cause already is called; I just want some how to update this array().

```
$project_Ids=array();
    function generateProperties($listP, $sizeS){
        global $project_Ids;             
        $i=0;
        foreach ($listP as $pr) {   
            $i++;   
                        $pr['project_id'];

                        $project_Ids[$i]=$pr['project_id'];

               echo "<li class='' style='cursor: pointer;height:" . $sizeSmallBlock . "px;' dds='" . $project['project_id'] . '-' . $project['project_calendar_id'] . "' id='" . $project['project_id'] . '-' . $project['project_calendar_id'] . "'>" . 
                $description . 
             "</li>";

        }        
    }
```

Comment: You could try to use return in your function.

Comment: var_dump()? what's out of function? Isn't `global`?

Comment: use $_POST['project_Ids_temp'] = $project_Ids; then the $_POST['project_Ids_temp'] is available outside!

Comment: var_dump()? what's out of function? Isn't global?array empty

Comment: This is an array . Are you sure it will work with  $_POST['project_Ids_temp'] = $project_Ids;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the array inside the function, and then have the function *return* it!

```
function generateProperties($listP, $sizeS){
    $project_Ids=array();          
    $i=0;
    foreach ($listP as $pr) {   
        $i++;   
        $project_Ids[$i]=$pr['project_id'];
    }
    return $project_Ids;        
}

// then elsewhere in your code
$project_Ids = generateProperties($listP, $sizeS);
```

Edit:

From looking at your foreach loop - it seems you are just getting the array values and storing them in an array? If so - just use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) - it does exactly what you want in one line of code:

```
$project_Ids = array_values($listP);
```

Comment: I can't call the function cause already is called; I just want some how to update this array().<br/> Is there any way?

Comment: Already called from where? That makes no sense. Besides - just use array_values - and you dont even need the function

Comment: I have the array of $project_Ids. in var_dump I can see them. But out of function array is empty

Comment: ...you are "saving" them to a variable right? See my editted answer.

Comment: This function works well(by drag and drop function calls). I want to use it also for returning an array (to show project_Ids).

Comment: Vahid - it *is* returning an array. I'm not sure what else you are expecting here...

Answer (score 0):

It is already available outside of the function, as you have correctly defined it outside.

You may want to brush up on [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$project_Ids = generateProperties($listP, $sizeS);
```

This will work but you have to read it from end of the page after rendering all the page :)